# Annihilator and Projective Dimension

Tags: ring-theory, projective-module

I was reading the book [A Course in Ring Theory by Passman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821836803) and in it is the following lemma;

[image]

and after this lemma there's a example which I don't quite understand;

[image]

The main thing that I don't understand is the structure of the ring $R$. What is meant by $K[x]$ and why is $R=K\dot{+}K\,\overline{x}$ ? I hope somebody can clarify these to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K[x]$ means the polynomial ring over $K$. You can prove $K[X]/(x^2)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum $K\dot{+}K\bar{x}$, where $\bar{x}^2=0$, by thinking about the homomorphism $$\phi:K[X]\to K\dot{+}K\bar{x}$$
sending $p(x)$ to $p(\bar{x})$, which is also just the remainder of $p(x)$ when divided by $x^2$ (except with $x$ replaced by $\bar{x}$). The kernel of this map is the ideal $(x^2)$, and $\phi$ is surjective, so $K[x]/(x^2)$ is isomorphic to $K\dot{+}K\bar{x}$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering. But how do you know that elements of $K\dot{+}K\bar{x}$ is  of the form $p(\bar{x})$? I mean aren't the elements of $K\dot{+}K\bar{x}$ is of the form $(k_1,\,k_2 \bar{x})$ ?

Comment: You should reread page 7 on the difference between external and internal direct sums. In general, the substitution $p(\bar{x})$ is going to have the form $k_1+k_2\bar{x}$, because $\bar{x}^2=0$ ensures all the higher powers in $p(x)$ will be annhilated.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read that page and now I understand what you mean. I want to confirm my understanding about how to show that that the annihilator of $a$ is equal to bR. Tell me whether this is correct: By the definition of the right annihilator $ann(a)=\{r=k_1+k_2a\in R\mid a(k_1+k_2a)=0\}$. Since $a^2=0$ we have, $ak_1=0$. Since $a$ is any arbitrary element(the indeterminate) this implies $k_1=0$. Hence, $ann(a)=k_2 a=k_2a=k_2b$ (since $a=b$) and since $k_2\in K$ is arbitrary, $ann(a)=bR$. Am I correct?